# Is it possible to access the player API form a web interface without registering an app?

Tags: spotify

I want to use spotify play to integrate with an artist's website.  I want to be able to access the player API to play items embedded from spotify as part of a combined playlist.

is this possible?

thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about the Apps API, which is only available inside the Spotify client.

However, the [Spotify Play Button](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/) might be what you're after.

Comment: Yes,  but is there a player API for the spotify play button, like there is with souncloud, vimeo, and youtube?